# Adding an init-container to a pod in a standard Helm chart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, database-backups

I am using a standard PostgreSQL Helm chart for deploying the database to a Kubernetes cluster. I need to add logic to the deployment procedure for loading the latest database backup into PostgreSQL. I would like to create an init container for a master pod defined in statefulsets.yaml.

I can add the init container definition directly in statefulsets.yaml template of PostgreSQL chart. I would like to avoid doing that for obvious reasons (applying Open/Closed Principle).

How can I add an init container to PostgreSQL master without modifying the standard Helm chart (e.g., from values.yaml)?

Is there a better way to load the database backup (other than an init container)?

Comment: Look into kustomize. I don't use helm to apply anything, just helm template then kusztomize (to add customizations). It can all be versioned together.

Comment: refer `postgresqlInitdbArgs` at https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql for init container configurations

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something via values.yaml "without modifying the standard Helm chart" sounds a bit contradictory because the `values.yaml` itself is part of the chart.

If you still need something more sophisticated to get the DB prepared, and want to stick with the "Open/Closed Principle", you might draw the border between the "Open" and "Closed" in the following manner for example:

- "Closed part": keep the `initContainers` section in the Statefulset as
  a "placeholder" with something like `exit 0` as the containers'
  command;
- "Open part": provide actual values for the `initContainers`
  "image" and "command" as part of `values.html`.

That way your statefulset will look closed for changes but open for extensions via values.html.

Comment: I can override the values in the standard chart using my values.yaml if the chart has an extension point. I need a way to copy a backup file from an S3-like repository to the PostgreSQL pod. I am not sure how I can do that using postgresqlInitdbArgs  value, which is just an environment variable.

Comment: Well, you're right regards `postgresqlInitdbArgs`; I've thought about it as the psql command line arguments. Have edited my answer.